# PCAP nanosecond resolution from Java

Tags: java, pcap, libpcap, tcpdump, jnetpcap

## Context

### Current status

For performance analysis, my company is interested in nanosecond resolution. So far, we have been using **hardware timestamps** and the support of nanoseconds was quickly hacked into the C [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) library.

It seems that the support for nanoseconds has now been added to the library (see other Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636334/read-nanosecond-pcap-file-using-libpcap)), and the last version on the [git repository](http://www.tcpdump.org/#source) makes the following method available:

```
pcap_open_offline_with_tstamp_precision(pathname, PCAP_TSTAMP_PRECISION_NANO, errbuf);
```

### Future

The thing is, C has proven itself to be hardly maintainable, difficultly scalable and since we use the capture for **analysis** only, we feel like we could benefit from using **Java** instead. Being able to use a proper IDE, Maven, build web-services, etc. seems more important than speed of execution when it comes to performance analysis.

I first hoped to be able to use [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/) but I can't find out how to support nanosecond resolution with that Java binding of libpcap.

---

## Question

### jNetPcap

Does anyone know an easy way to read Pcap files with nanosecond precision, using jNetPcap?

**Update:** I just found mention of a [`TimestampResolution`](http://jnetpcap.sourceforge.net/docs/capture-0.7/api/index.html?jnetpcap/capture/CaptureInterface.TimestampResolution.html) enum in jNetPcap's Javadoc. I will try to use that and update my answer later.

***Note:*** I have also asked about nanosecond resolution directly on [jNetPcap's support forum](http://jnetpcap.com/node/1140?1868639987=1), and will update my question if I get any answer on that side...

### Other solutions

Does anyone know about another way to profit from Java's ecosystem while still being able to read PCap files with nanosecond precision?

---

Thanks! :)

Comment: I haven't read the whole post, but is `System.nanoTime()` what you are searching?

Comment: Not at all, hehe! [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) will give the value of the most precise available timer. It only allows for performance analysis within a given Java program. Read the rest of the post: in my case, I have hardware timestamp in a PCAP file, and I want to calculate latencies **a posteriori**

Comment: Sorry for not reading the whole post. If LGPL is not a problem for you, you could just fork the jNetPcap project and add nanosecond precision. It's just a wrapper if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old, but just in case someone else has this need- if using jNetPcap is not a must, [pcap4j](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j) seems to support it.

To open a cap:

```
PcapHandle h = Pcaps.openOffline(fname, PcapHandle.TimestampPrecision.NANO);
```

To read packet and timestamp:

```
Packet nextPacket = h.getNextPacket();
Timestamp timestamp = h.getTimestamp();
```

Hope that helps!