# pcap nanoseconds Python

Tags: python, pcap, libpcap

Is there anyway to get nanoseconds out of a pcap with existing python libraries? I have a nanoseconds pcap file that works just fine with Wireshark but the Python [pcapy](http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy) library will not even import the file.

This functionality does exist in c libpcap (see: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636334/read-nanosecond-pcap-file-using-libpcap_)) but has anyone ported it into Python? I took a look at the source code but it is over my head in changing pcapy to allow this.

Nanoseconds are necessary for what I am doing and microseconds do not give me the necessary precision, though my code is working perfectly fine with micros.

Comment: Maybe try switching library. FTR, Scapy supports nanoseconds précision in pcaps

Answer (score 3):

After trying every existing pcap module in Python, we decided to edit the source on pcapy. We changed this to include the "pcap_open_offline_with_tstamp_precision(pathname, PCAP_TSTAMP_PRECISION_NANO, errbuf);" functionality that already existed in libpcap and it worked perfectly. Now we have nanosecond resolution for our packet capture analysis.

Comment: Your improvement in pcapy to support nanosecond precision timestamps sounds very useful.  Can you share your implementation of the change?

Answer (score 0):

Within each packet, if you use:

header.getts()[0]

It will return the epoch time. I'm using:

def convert_timefromepoch(epochTimestamp):
    return time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(epochTimestamp))

timeStamp = convert_timefromepoch(header.getts()[0])

to get a string of the date/time for use in my output.