# libpcap timestamp resolution

Tags: python, pcap

I am using python module pypcap (simplified object-oriented Python wrapper for libpcap). I am having troubles with timestamp resolution. In my pcap file I can see my packets have nanosecond precision, but when I parse the pcap file in python and extact the timestamp from a particular packet, it only has microsecond precision?

```
import pcap
for ts, pkt in pcap.pcap():
    print ts, `pkt`
```

ts has microsecond precision. I want nanosecond precision, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764341/pcap-nanoseconds-python

Comment: Yes, it is definately related. But I would prefer not to modify the modules source code unless 100% necessary.
This is a very brutal solution. Whats when you bump versions?

Comment: Did the getts() answer make any sense there?  I suspect it doesn't, but don't want you to miss it.

Comment: To be honest, no his solution doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Old question, anyone ever find a solution to this? Other than modifying the module's source code

Comment: It looks like nanosecond precision is supported by the latest version now.