# reading nanosecond resolution from recorded pcap files in C++

Tags: c++, timestamp, libpcap

I've recorded some pcap files with tcpdump with option `--time-stamp-precision nano` given,

and I can print the timestamps of these pcap files with tcpdump using a command like

`tcpdump -r <my_pcap_file> -ttt`

However, I can't seem to read the timestamp using libpcap, the best I'm getting now is microsecond resolution.

I found a recent post here that mentions that it's not supported yet in libpcap: 
https://github.com/google/gopacket/issues/298

Is this still true? Or do I need to check out `pcapgo` mentioned in the post?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the post below answered my question!

[Read nanosecond pcap file using libpcap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636334/read-nanosecond-pcap-file-using-libpcap?rq=1)

At first I was using a pcap file that actually had microsecond resolution,
and I assumed that using 
`pcap_open_offline_with_tstamp_precision(pathname, PCAP_TSTAMP_PRECISION_NANO, errbuf);`
to open the pcap file should make the `tv_usec` in `struct timeval` be in nanoseconds, but this seems to be true only when the pcap file actually has nanosecond time stamps.